# Wordpress search results look wierd with custom theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, search

I have been building my website using wordpress and my own custom theme. I can't figure out why the search results page is so messed up.

[Link to search results page](https://www.landdesigns.nl/?s=Motion&cmp_bypass=1)

[screenshot of search results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM60D.png)

Can anyone help me figure this out? If you need to take a look at a piece of code, just ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress gives different classes to `<body>` for a different pages via `body_class()` function. One of them is 'search'. I guess you applied this class to a seachform or something like this.

This come from style.css line 460 -

```
display: flex;
max-width: 500px;
```

Just rename searchform class to avoid such behavior or try

```
.search:not(body) {
    // css goes here
}
```